# Copying data file into an array

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a project for school. They gave me a data file that needs to be in an array of 10*10. This array needs to be an upper triangle, which means that all values of and below the diagonal have to be zero. This data file is the time that a project takes by every stage. It means that every [i][j] represents the time for stage from i to j.
Just to make it more complicated the problem ask you to find the longest time per column and add it to the longest time in the next column.
here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//Function prototype
int minCompletionTime (int Data[], int numTasks);

int main()
{
    //Declaring and initializing variables
    int num_Events(0), completion_Time(0);
    int startSearch(0), endSearch(0);
    const int SIZE(10);
    char datch;

    //Declaring an array to hold the duration of each composite activity
    int rows(0),duration_Data [10];

    //Declaring an input filestream and attaching it to the data file
    ifstream dataFile;
    dataFile.open("duration.dat");

    //Reading the data file and inputting it to the array. Reads until eof
    //marker is read
    while (!dataFile.eof())
    {
        //Declaring an index variable for the array

        //Reading data into elements of the array
        dataFile >> duration_Data[rows];

        //Incrementing the index variable
        rows++;

    }
    //Taking input for the number of events in the project
    cout << "Enter the number of events in the project >>> ";
    cin  >> num_Events;

    //Calling the function to calculate the minimum completion time 
    completion_Time = minCompletionTime(duration_Data, num_Events);

    //Outputting the minimum completion time
    cout << "The minimum time to complete this project is " << completion_Time
        << "." << endl;

}

int minCompletionTime (int Data[], int numTasks)
{
    int sum=0;
    //As long as the index variable is less than the number of tasks to be
    //completed, the time to complete the task stored in each cell will be 
    //added to a sum variable
    for (int Idx=0; Idx < numTasks ; Idx++)
    {
        sum += Data[Idx];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated
 My data file only has 6 elements that holds this elements: 9 8 0 0 7 5 
my data should look like this in order to start doing operations.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 9 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

It is a little confusing. I am sorry. The first and second column should have values of zero and first row the same way. after fifth row should be all zeros as well since it will be filled with more information from other data file.

Comment: @lolo1116 How does the data file look like, can you show an example? And what's wrong with your code, what doesn't work? Be more specific.

Comment: my array should look like this:

Comment: Why don't you edit the question.

Comment: I just edited but It wont let me stack them up as a matrix.

Comment: Is this ok? Just highlight the text and press Ctrl+K. (or indent each line by 4 spaces)

Comment: The data format is still fairly unclear -- you say the file has 5 elements, but list 6 in one place and 10 in another. You list 9 and 8 as apparently separate elements in one place, but then show only one number containing 98.

Comment: Where's the structure to hold a 10x10 array?

Comment: The question need to be flagged as homework

Comment: making the array is one of problems how to make it knowing that more values will be assigned to it.

Comment: @Nawaz: Even alleged "experienced C++ programmers" routinely struggle to read files right... :-( That `eof` just sounds sooo tempting.

Comment: thank you @Nawaz Ill see if I can use other method

Comment: @lolo1116: `int myArray[10][10];` Fill in the values as needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of solving this problem. Here are 2 very naive ways:

**1. Use a 10x10 array:**

- Read everything in from the data file (`dataFile >> data[row][col]`).
- Have 2 nested loops:

  - The outer loop iterates over columns.
  - The inner loop iterates over the rows of that specific column.
  - Since you have to find the max and the values under the diagonal is zero, you can just be lazy and find the max of each column (you might have trouble if it's a lot larger than 10x10). However, if you want to only go through the rows that are necessary, I'll let you figure it out (it's very simple, don't over think).

**2. Only use a 1x10 array:**

- Initialize the array with the minimal value (0 or -1 should work for you), let's call it the `max_row`.
- Read item by item on each row, and compare it to the value that's stored in the `max_row` and replace appropriately.
- When you're done, just sum up the elements in `max_row`.